# Angular apply same success and error function bodies to different $http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I am not sure what exact keywords to search for this. So I decided to ask here for help.

I think this is more a **JavaScript related question** rather than angular. Anyways here is my problem.

**I am in a DRY situation** (don't repeat yourself). I am trying to merge the two of my **$http.put** and **$http.delete** methods' success and error function under single one, because they share the same functionalities.

#### Here is my current code

```
// Delete permanenty button action
  $scope.delete_donor = function(form) {
    $http.delete(url)
      .success(function() {
        // @TODO DRY? DELETE UPDATE delete_donor update_donor
        response.ipv4 = INT_TO_STR_IP(response.ipv4)
        // Show deleted data to user after operation
        $scope.donor.saved_data = response.saved_data
        $location.path("/")
      })
      .error(function(response) {
        $scope.donor.validation_errors = SERVER_VALIDATION_ERROR(response)
      })
  }
  // Save changes button action
  $scope.update_donor = function(form) {
    var body = $scope.donor.data
    delete body.ipv4
    $http.put(url, body)
      .success(function(response) {
        // @TODO DRY? DELETE UPDATE delete_donor update_donor
        response.ipv4 = INT_TO_STR_IP(response.ipv4)
        // Show new updated data to user after operation
        $scope.donor.saved_data = response.saved_data
        $location.path("/")
      })
      .error(function(response) {
        $scope.donor.validation_errors = SERVER_VALIDATION_ERROR(response)
      })
```

As you can see $http.delete().success().error() and $http.put().success().error() methods are same.

#### I am trying to do something like

```
WHATSTHIS unify(response) {
  WOOT .success(function(response) { // SAME CODE BODY })
  WOOT .error(function(response) { // SAME CODE BODY })
}

// Delete permanenty button action
  $scope.delete_donor = function(form) {
    $http.delete(url)
      .unify(response)
  }
  // Save changes button action
  $scope.update_donor = function(form) {
    var body = $scope.donor.data
    delete body.ipv4
    $http.put(url, body)
      .unify(response)
```

#### I just know one way to achieve something similiar which is:

```
var unifySuccess = function(response) {
  // DO
}
var unifySuccess = function(response) {
  // DO
}

// Delete permanenty button action
  $scope.delete_donor = function(form) {
    $http.delete(url)
      .sucesss(unifySuccess)
      .error(unifyError)
```

But maybe there is an other clever way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what version of Angular you're using, but as of 1.4 the `.success().error()` thing is [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/error/$http/legacy), and for good reason. I'd recommend reading [this article](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/)

Comment: @JesseAmano Thanks for information! I will definetly check the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you could do is create your own http request service that will do these functionalities and return the promise as a response

something like this

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('proxyHttp', function($http) {
    return function(options) {
      return $http(options)
        .then(
          function() {
            // success callback
          },
          function() {
            // error callback
          });
    }
  })
```

**Update: For example**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .service('proxyHttp', function($http, $q) {
    return function(options) {
      console.log('Run proxy http');

      return $http(options)
        .then(
          function(response, status) {
            console.log('always do this on success');
            // success callback

            return response;
            // here we return the response or what ever you want,
            // and we can continue handling it
          })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('we failed!');
          // error callback

          return $q.reject();
        })
    }
  })
  .controller('testController', function($scope, proxyHttp) {
    $scope.testError = function() {
      console.log('Run test error method');

      proxyHttp({
          url: 'http://www.google.com',
          method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(
          function() {})
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('we continue handling our error here...');
        });
    }


    $scope.testSuccess = function() {
      console.log('Run test success method');

      proxyHttp({
          url: 'http://httpbin.org/ip',
          method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(
          function(response) {
            console.log('continue chaining after success for the original promise');
            console.log('Response data: '
              response.data.origin);
            console.log('read more about pomise and chaining here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise');
          })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('error');
        });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <button ng-click="testError()">Click Me for error!</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="testSuccess()">Click Me for success!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think I need something more native javascript solution but I will consider using this in future. @WalksAway I am concerned about going for a angular service or a native solution. What would you suggest?

Comment: if you are working with angular i suggest using angular standards and structural design, have a look at this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md , when i use angular i do my best to work with services and directives... becuase thats the *angular way*

Comment: hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the guide and the answer. May I ask for an example to how to use this code?

Comment: sure but I'm not home right now, but expect it in like ~3 hours

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen i added a working example, just run the code snippet and play with it :) hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual use case, this may end up sacrificing too much readability to be helpful, but since you asked specifically for cleverness:

```
function attachHttpResponseHandling(httpPromise) {
    httpPromise
        .success(function(response) {
            response.ipv4 = INT_TO_STR_IP(response.ipv4);
            // Show new updated data to user after operation
            $scope.donor.saved_data = response.saved_data;
            $location.path("/");
        })
        .error(function(response) {
            $scope.donor.validation_errors = SERVER_VALIDATION_ERROR(response);
        })
    ;
}
// Delete permanenty button action
$scope.delete_donor = function(form) {
    attachHttpResponseHandling($http.delete(url));
};
// Save changes button action
$scope.update_donor = function(form) {
    var body = $scope.donor.data;
    delete body.ipv4;
    attachHttpResponseHandling($http.put(url, body));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though that is exactly what I was wanted, I had to mark the other answer because to not guide someone in future doing things in my wrong way rather than angular way

Comment: No worries; I already upvoted that answer the other day for the same reason.